# Getting " MultiValueDictKeyError at /button/ 'text " error in a Django project

Tags: django, post, multivalue

Tring to create a demo Todo web app using Django and Bootstrap,
Whenever I am trying to trigger a function using a button it's raising a "MultiValueDictKeyError at /button/" Error. I have set an input form name "text" and receiving it

**This is the view function**

```
def index(request):

    todoData = Todo.objects.all().order_by("date")
    return render(request, 'index.html',{
         "todo": todoData

         }
        )
@csrf_exempt
def submit(request):
     current_date = timezone.now()
     content = request.POST["text"]
     Todo.objects.create(date = current_date , text = content)

     return render(request,'index.html')
```

**Here's the "index.html"**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}


{% block content %}
<div class='row mt-4'>
    <div class='col'>
        <h2>Add Task :</h2>
                <form class='form-inline'action='button/' method='POST' name="text">
                   <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" placeholder="text here...">
                   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Add</button>
                                                        </form>
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class='col mt-4'>
       <ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>

</ul>
   </div>

{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

name="text" should be inside input type text like`<input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" placeholder="text here..." name="text">`

Not in form element.